# How to create a time-driven trigger that runs from 11 am to 2 pm?

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

I am trying to build a script that should run every Tuesday, Wednesday, and Thursday between 11 am to 2 pm and after every 10 minutes.

For e.g. If today is Tuesday.. then the script will start executing at 11 am morning and will execute after every 10 min and then should stop executing at 2 pm on that day.

Now I am trying with programmatically setting the triggers like below:

```
function startCustomTrigger()
{
  
  //first remove all existing triggers - for safty
   removeTriggers(false);
  
  //script will run every minute defined  
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('StartProcess').timeBased().onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.TUESDAY).onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.WEDNESDAY).onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.THURSDAY).atHour(11).everyMinutes(10).create();
  
  
  //script will run every minute defined  
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('StopProcess').timeBased().onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.TUESDAY).onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.WEDNESDAY).onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.THURSDAY).atHour(2).create();
 
}


function StopProcess()
{
   //first remove all existing triggers - for safety
   removeTriggers(false);`enter code here`
  
  //script will run every minute defined  
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('startCustomTrigger').timeBased().onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.TUESDAY).onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.WEDNESDAY).onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.THURSDAY).atHour(10).create();
  
}
```

Comment: Google Quotas for Triggers is 1 hour a day.  [Google Documentation - Quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas)

Comment: Did not get it.... Can you please explain what does that mean?  Does that mean if my script is running continuously then it will run for max 1 hr and then will stop automatically?

Comment: I want to run the script on Tuesday, Wednesday and Thursday between 11 AM to 2 PM after every 10 minutes.... will that cause any quota limitations?  What if I implement Amit's suggestion.. so the script will will every day after 10 minutest but as I have if condition to check current day and hr the main function will execute at desired schedule only..... will this also cause quota limitation problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also consider having a single trigger that runs every 10 minutes and, inside the trigger function, you can check the time and weekday. The code is executed only if all conditions are met else it returns without doing anything.

```
function startCustomTrigger()
{
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('StartProcess').timeBased().everyMinutes(10).create();
}

function StartProcess() {

  var date = new Date();  
  var day = date.getDay();
  var hrs = date.getHours();

  if ((day >= 2) && (day <= 4) && (hrs >= 11) && (hrs <= 14)) {

     // Add your code here

  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Actually I am using your GmailMailMerge Script (Free Version) and wanted to have some modifications in the script to make it run in some time range only. I will try your suggestions and will raise question again here if found any problem. Hope this is fine with you.

Comment: It is fine here with the Date class. However, one can get in trouble with getDay(). In some places, it will return the day of the month as opposed to the week. (For example, see: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/date-field#getDay()).
I guess the lesson is, even if you feel comfortable with what you are doing, it does not hurt to read the docs.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to set up lots of triggers to do this.

- You need three weekly triggers; each one to run on each of the three
  days
- Those three triggers, will pragmatically create a trigger to run every 10 minutes.
- You need three more weekly triggers; each one to run on each of the three
  days to shut down the triggers that are running every 10 minutes, otherwise, they will just continue to run forever

So, you need seven triggers.  Three to run on that specific day, that will then create a trigger to run every 10 minutes starting at 10am.  One trigger that will start at 10am and keep running indefinitely (until you shut it off).  And three triggers to stop the trigger that is running every 10 minutes.

[image: Trigger On Day]

The triggers that will run on a specific day, should be set up manually.  So, 6 of the triggers will be set up manually.  The trigger that runs every 10 minutes needs to be created and deleted from code.

The six triggers that are a "Week timer", to run on a specific day, only need to run once to create the trigger that will run every 10 minutes.  I'd run them an hour earlier than you want the 10 minute triggers to run, just to make sure they are set to go.

Comment: Hi Thank you for reply. I have setup some triggers like you have suggested but then after Amit Agarwal replied to my question, I feel his solution would be simple to implement. Will try and raise question again in case of any issues. Thanks again and I appreciate your efforts to reply my question with a solution.