# Syntax Error Recuring Emails schedule

Tags: javascript, date, google-apps-script

I'm trying to create a program that sends emails based on a schedule.

If the email is set to daily it will run daily. If weekly weekly etc.

I keep getting syntax error on the "var mDaily =" line. Do I have too many && and ||? Will this program properly time the emails to be Monday - Friday and at the times scheduled?

Thanks!!! Only been coding a few months!!!

```
 function startCustomTrigger()
     {
      ScriptApp.newTrigger("recurringEmails").timeBased().everyMinutes(60).create();
    }



function recurringEmails() {

//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28565372/time-based-google-script-should-run-between-11am-to-2pm

function recurPostLoadsSchedule() {

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Contacts");
  //var start = dataSheet.getRange("H2").getValue();
  //var end = dataSheet.getRange("H3").getValue();

  var dataRange = dataSheet.getRange("F4:N");
  var info = dataRange.getValues();


 for (var i = 0; i < dataSheet.getLastRow(); i++){



  var date = new Date();  
  var day = date.getDay();
  var hrs = date.getHours();
  var dom = date.getdate();

  if ((day >= 1) && (day <= 5) && (hrs >= 6) && (hrs <= 17 )) {

var mDaily = if ((info[i][9] == "Email Multiple Daily") && (day >= 1) && (day <= 5) && (hrs >= 7) && (hrs <= 8 ) 
|| (hrs >= 10) && (hrs <= 11 ) || (hrs >= 14) && (hrs <= 15)){

askForLoads() //this is actually the email program for the specific 

};

var daily = if ((info[i][9] == "Email Daily") && (day >= 1) && (day <= 5) && (hrs >= 8) && (hrs <= 9)){

askForLoads()

};


var mWeekly = if((info[i][9] == "Email Multiple Weekly") && (day == 1) || (day == 3) || (day == 4) && (hrs >= 9) && (hrs <= 10)){

askForLoads()

};


var weekly = if((info[i][9] == "Email Weekly") && (dom == 1) || (dom == 5) || (dom == 9) || (dom == 13)|| (dom == 17)
|| (dom == 21) || (dom == 25) || (dom == 29) && (hrs >= 8) && (hrs <= 9)){ //1-2 per week

askForLoads()

};


var monthly = if((info[i][9] == "Email Monthly") && (dom == 1) || (dom == 11) || (dom == 21) || (dom == 31) && (hrs >= 10) && (hrs <= 11 )){ //1-3 per month

askForLoads()

};

};

};

};

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use if on a var declaration.

You have two options:

1) Either you move the variable declaration inside the if statement:

```
if ((info[i][9] == "Email Multiple Daily")&& (day >= 1)&& (day <= 5) && (hrs >= 7) && (hrs <= 8)  || (hrs >= 10) && (hrs <= 11 ) || (hrs >= 14) && (hrs <= 15)) { var mDaily = askForLoads(); };
```

2) Or you use the simplified handler `(condition) ? true : false;`

```
var mDaily = ((info[i][9] == "Email Multiple Daily")&& (day >= 1)&& (day <= 5) && (hrs >= 7) && (hrs <= 8)  || (hrs >= 10) && (hrs <= 11 ) || (hrs >= 14) && (hrs <= 15)) ? askForLoads() : null;
```

*PS: As an aside note, I think your && and || conditions needs more parenthesis for clarity, btw.*

Comment: The var are not needed at all now that you say that. Just wroting it down I meeded to remember which formula I was working with. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
var mDaily = if ((info[i][9] == "Email Multiple Daily") && (day >= 1) && (day <= 5) && (hrs >= 7) && (hrs <= 8 ) 
|| (hrs >= 10) && (hrs <= 11 ) || (hrs >= 14) && (hrs <= 15)){

askForLoads() //this is actually the email program for the specific 

};
```

`if` statements don't return values, so it doesn't make sense to assign it to `mDaily`. Do you mean to declare `var mDaily = askForLoads()` inside the `if` statement?

From context it's not really clear what the responsibilities of `mDaily` and `daily` are.

Comment: The var are not needed at all now that you say that. Just wroting it down I meeded to remember which formula I was working with. Thanks for your help!