# Scheduling Google App Script function for specific recurring windows

Tags: google-apps-script, crontrigger

I'm trying to schedule an Apps Script function. I need the email to trigger Mon-Sat every 2 hours starting at 11am-9pm.

I've written the following code to create triggers for each day:

```
function createTriggers() {

  var days = [ScriptApp.WeekDay.MONDAY, 
              ScriptApp.WeekDay.TUESDAY,
              ScriptApp.WeekDay.WEDNESDAY, 
              ScriptApp.WeekDay.THURSDAY, 
              ScriptApp.WeekDay.FRIDAY,
              ScriptApp.WeekDay.SATURDAY];

  for (var i=0; i<days.length; i++) { 
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('emailDashboard')
      .timeBased().onWeekDay(days[i])
      .everyWeeks(1).everyHours(2).create();
  }
}
```

When I run what I have above, I get the following error:

> "The recurrence interval on the clock trigger has already been set. (line 79, file "Code")"

I cant find anything about that response, and it doesn't actually create the trigger. I assume what I have above would get me the email Mon-Sat, every 2 hours. I'm not sure how to go about starting at 11am central and ending at 9pm central.

Comment: What is wrong with what you have?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: When I run what I have above I get the following error "The recurrence interval on the clock trigger has already been set. (line 79, file "Code")" I cant find anything about that response and it doesnt actually trigger the email to send. I assume what I have above would get me the email Mon-Sat every 2 hours. I'm not sure how to go about starting at 11am central and ending at 9pm central.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue comes from over-specificity. Many of the options you use, like `onWeekDay` and `everyWeeks`, are mutually exclusive. You can read more about the class on its [Apps Script reference page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/trigger-builder).

A much simpler approach is to schedule the granularity you desire:

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction").timeBased().everyHours(2).create();
```

and then check whether the current time meets the criteria you have:

1. It's not Sunday
2. Hour greater than 11 am local
3. Hour less than 9 pm local

It's worth noting that Google will run your function at a minute value of its choosing when you use the hour level of specificity.

As with other triggered functions, there is an available [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#time-driven_events)

An example discriminator that assumes you only care about UTC values (which are the locale for all values in the event object):

```
function getsCalledByClockTrigger(e) {
  if(!e) throw new Error("Called from the Script Editor");
  else console.log(e); // Show this event object in Stackdriver logs.

  // Check that it isn't UTC Sunday.
  if(e["day-of-week"] === 7)
    return;

  // Checking the UTC hour is between 11 AM and 9 PM.
  if(e.hour < 11 || e.hour > 21)
    return;

  /* Do stuff */
}
```

A discriminator for non-UTC values would probably be simplest with `var now = new Date()` and checking various [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) properties like [`now.getDay()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay).

Comment: Thanks! I found a snippet on another question here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28565372/time-based-google-script-should-run-between-11am-to-2pm?rq=1]

Comment: @S1ick1 I've added some example code as well